# can i build a java desktop application without sql knoledge

Tags: java, sql, database, desktop-application

i am not a pro with programming, and i'm trying to build a desktop app with java, but i need to combine it with sql in order to store a lot of info in a table (database..)

and when i googled i found hours of tutorials to learn sql,
i'm still struggling with java and i have no time to deal with sql too...
can i do this without learn the sql language and all...?

do i have to sit down and study it all or is there another way around?

(p.s. sorry, i think my english not that good...)

Comment: Well, if you think your application requires a SQL database, then yes, you have to learn that.  Sorry, but this question is too vague.  Since you really don't share much detail, hard to know. 
 Do you need to persist multiple tables?  Is the app multi-user? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  thanks

Comment: I would say yes. Just sit down and start building features you want. Technically you can avoid doing SQL stuff by using ORM like OrmLite, but SQL is something really good to know. Don't worry too much. Just start building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's some options:

- Use files instead of a database. You can make use of serialization to store your instances directly on files.
- Use a non relational database so you won't have to deal with learning SQL
- Use an SQL database but search for an ORM. ORMs let you interact with relational databases without typing SQL directly (but you can if you need to when necessary)

Comment: thanks! i'll try files.
one more thing, can java work with excel files?

Comment: Sure, you just need to download a package that gives you those functionalitie. This one it's for all microsoft documents https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Awesome! thank you!